# AMD FX 4130 overclock-How to overclock the CPU from the BIOS

Tags: cpu, overclocking, cpu-speed

Well I've been using my CPU for awhile now but I want to unlock it's full power but when it comes to CPU overclocking I've never been good with it nor taken the time to learn it from these bad video's on the subject.

If anyone here has the knowledge to Overclock from the BIOS (and yes I know it's dangerous but I'm willing to take the risk) so if any of you know I would like to know please, all my PC specs are below:

```
ASUS 78LMT USB 3.0 Motherboard
Gigabyte Geforce GTX 560 Non-TI SOC edition (overclocked by me with MSI Afterburner)
AMD FX 4130 quad-core CPU 3.6 GHZ
DDR3 RAM 3 stick = 8GB
8 fans (including CPU and graphics)
Corsiar PSU 750W Gold edition
```

Comment: You should consult the documentation for your motherboard to determine the specific procedure. Look at this question for a general outline: http://superuser.com/questions/17513/what-steps-do-you-take-when-overclocking

Answer (score 2):

Check the user manual for your motherboard on the Gigabyte website. There appear to be two variations of your motherboard, here is the link for the S2PT model. http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-78lmt-s2pt_v.3.1_e.pdf

Page 23 has instructions for overclocking settings.